# How to disable some options in react-select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select

I am facing issue in disabling some selected values in react-select. I searched for doc and found some but its not working. I have attached the code snippet for a better view -

```html
<Select
  name="selectUsdAdmin"
  id="selectUsdAdmin"
  value={this.state.usdAdminValue}
  options={this.state.usdOptions}
  onChange={this.handleUsdAdminChange}
  multi
  className={!this.state.isUsdAdminSelectValid ? "is-invalid" : ""}
/>;
```

I tried using **isDisabled** prop which is mentioned in the docs but it is for disabling the whole select box. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: A detail explanation would also be appreciated.. If possible create a working example and explain which option you want to disable and what is the condition to disable such options?? Some needed info are missing..

Comment: I will share a working example of my issue.